# JSON files with encoding problems at the strings (Accent characters like \u00xx)

Tags: json, database, string, dictionary, encoding

So, i've been trying to export and filter some queries to a MySQL database to JSON files, and after i have tried everything to fix this in the 'code' i'm using to export i can't fix it.

The text sections looks good except for the spanish characters (Mainly accents) that are replaced for a `\u00x` value, for example:

```
[{..., "lang_tweet": "es", "text_tweet": "Recuerdo un d\u00eda de, *llamada a la 1:45*, \"Micho... Que me muero.!!\",...},...]
```

So my question is directly if there is anyway i can take this JSON file, proccess it and fix the errors? If it exist a way, how can i do it? Any help would be thankful since i have this error since yesterday and i need to fix it soon.

Take a look to the JSON complete file i want to fix:
https://github.com/Vichoko/real-time-twit/blob/master/auto_labeling/json/tweets_sismos/test2.json

Comment: There is absolutely *nothing wrong here.*

Comment: Thanks @deceze i'll take a look to that reference, meamwhile let me tell you that i find those strings wrong because I need to take them and train a classificator with them, so i need the accent characters as they are and not ase those capped char. I'm not used to manage that `\u00x` characters

Comment: Simply use a standard-adhering JSON parser to decode your JSON in your programming language of choice, done.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for your help dude. Look, i'm importing the JSON file with python `json.load(file)` and the strings in the parsed dict shows with wrong characters here too, but they are sightly different, as you can see here: `u'text_tweet': u'Recuerdo un d\xeda de, *llamada a la 1:45*, "Micho... Que me muero.!!"'`
I've read the refference but can't figure out how to fix it yet, sorry it's very hard to me understand encodings.

Comment: Different problem. The data is perfectly correct as far as JSON is concerned.

Comment: My problem is not that if the json is correct or not. I'm interested in using the strings as they should be. I understand that underlying those capped characters exista the real character i want to use. But i don't know how to recover the usable form of the JSON.

Comment: Your JSON expresses the string "...día...". Whether you like how it looks or not, that's the content of your JSON string. Your JSON is correct. Stop worrying about how the string looks in your JSON. Your problem is that you're somehow incorrectly parsing the data in Python, which turns it into the wrong representation in Python. To help you there, I need to see what exactly you're doing in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the help @deceze, more than this doubt you helped me to understand better how JSON files work, so thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

As @deceze said, the JSON is correct. If i do in Python:

```
with open("file.json", "r") as readfile:
    data = json.load(readfile)

print(data[0][u'text_tweet'])
```

It prints correcly the spanish characters:

```
> Recuerdo un día de, *llamada a la 1:45*, "Micho... Que me muero.!!"
```